# Is There a Way to Have a Value Stored in an Array Every Time the Loop Occurs in Ansible?

Tags: arrays, ansible, dns, active-directory

I have an `ansible-playbook` which aims to display an `A Record` of a particular host from a DNS Server within Domain Controller. Here’s what I did on Ansible-Playbook:

1. Use powershell to obtain information related to A Record on the DNS Server.
2. Save it as a variable named `test_var`.
3. Divide the contents of the variable `test_var` into line by line.
4. Retrieves the important line containing the string `host` I'm looking for.
5. Take the important attributes of those important lines and show it as `msg`.

Here's the code:

```
# hostname and domain are necessary
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    search_name: "{{hostname}}"
  tasks: 

    - name: powershell query
      win_shell: "Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -Name '{{hostname}}' -ZoneName '{{domain}}' -RRType A"
      register: result1
      when: (hostname is defined) and (domain is defined)
      
    - set_fact:
        test_var: "{{ result1.stdout_lines }}"
    
    - name: pickup lines
      set_fact:
        important_lines: "{{ important_lines |default([]) + [item] }}"
      with_items:
      - "{{ test_var }}"
    
    - name: find the line
      set_fact:
        target_line: "{{item}}"
      when: item|trim is search(search_name)
      loop: "{{ important_lines | flatten(1) }}"

    - name: get all attributes
      set_fact:
        attribute_record: "{{ target_line.split()[1]|trim}}"
        attribute_type: "{{ target_line.split()[2]|trim}}"
        attribute_timestamp: "{{ target_line.split()[3]|trim}}"
        attribute_timetolive: "{{ target_line.split()[4]|trim}}"
        attribute_ipaddress: "{{ target_line.split()[5]|trim}}"
        
    - name: print results
      debug:
        msg: "name: {{search_name}}, Ip Address: {{attribute_ipaddress}}"
```

And here's my DNS Server configuration:

[image]

And the results are as follows (host=test1):

[image]

However, I have a problem. In the `Find the line` task which runs the loop, the `target_line` variable stores only the last line at the end of the task. So, when the `print results` task is executed, only the last host and IP address are displayed. The question is, is there some way to have each line stored in an array every time the loop occurs? Thus, I can call the contents of the array to display it one by one. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution that I got:

```
# hostname and domain are necessary
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    correct_line: []
    search_name: "{{hostname}}"
  tasks: 

    - name: powershell query
      win_shell: "Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -Name '{{hostname}}' -ZoneName '{{domain}}' -RRType A"
      register: result1
      when: (hostname is defined) and (domain is defined)
      
    - set_fact:
        test_var: "{{ result1.stdout_lines }}"
    
    - name: pickup lines
      set_fact:
        important_lines: "{{ important_lines |default([]) + [item] }}"
      with_items:
      - "{{ test_var }}"
    
    - name: find the line
      set_fact:
        correct_line: "{{correct_line + [item]}}"
      when: item|trim is search(search_name)
      loop: "{{ important_lines | flatten(1) }}"
      
    - name: print results
      debug:
        msg: "name: {{item.split()[0]|trim}}, Ip Address: {{item.split()[5]|trim}}"
      loop: "{{ correct_line | flatten(1) }}"
```

And here's the result:
[image]